# Airflow - How to get an Airflow variable inside the bash command in Bash Operator?

Tags: bash, airflow

I have an Airflow variable
[image: Variable Airflow]

And I would like to get it inside a bash command on Bash Operator.

I tried:

```
t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'try_bash',
        bash_command="echo {{var.aa}}",
        dag=dag 

and

t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'try_bash',
        bash_command=" echo {{var.value.aa}}",
        dag=dag
```

I know that to get a variable I can do

```
Variable.get("aa")
```

But I would like to get it directly inside the bash command.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: `" echo {{ var.value.aa }}"` is the solution. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: [2021-09-03 18:40:07,106] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Output:
[2021-09-03 18:40:07,120] {subprocess.py:78} INFO - {{ var.value.aa }}


is this the result

it didn't return the real value of variable

Comment: Am I missing any import?
I used only from airflow.models import Variable

Comment: Please show the whole log of t2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.  Just a slight difference with what you originally had:

```py
t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id= 'try_bash',
    bash_command='echo "{{ var.value.aa }}"',
    dag=dag,
)
```

[image]